# Create custom control in asp.net with chosen.css and chosen.jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating custom control for DropDownList in asp.net using chosen.css and chosen.jquery.js. while building the application it gives the error and not creating the dll file

Error   1   Unexpected error creating debug information file 'C:\Users\Ultimate\Downloads\DropDownChosen\DropDownChosen\DropDownChosen\obj\Debug\DropDownChosen.PDB' -- 'C:\Users\Ultimate\Downloads\DropDownChosen\DropDownChosen\DropDownChosen\obj\Debug\DropDownChosen.pdb: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
'   DropDownChosen

this we cant debug then how to solve this problem....

The code was taken from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620313/Custom-ASP-NET-DropdownList-Control-Using-Chosen-j

Answer (score -1):

Well, it doesn't seem to be a problem related directly with programming, but with a file lock. Try with some tool like Unlocker to release the file lock.

http://filehippo.com/es/download_unlocker/

Comment: what is this filehippo man ? I want the solution and you are suggesting something else that is not related to my question

Comment: @skgacharya Of course it's related to your question, you should read by yourself the compiler message: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." With this tool you can unlock the locked PDB file. And try to be lees rude with someone who is helping for nothing ;-)